# Retrieve data from angular post request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, post, express

right now my situation is that I have a post request from an Angular module trying to send some data to an URL handled with node.js and Express.

**tickets.js:**

```
$http(
    {
        method: "post",
        url: "/ticketDetail",
        headers: {"application/json"},
        data: {detail : "test"}
    }).then(function successCallback(response)
    {
        $scope.detail = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response){});
```

**app.js:**

```
app.post("/ticketDetail", function(req, res)
{
    console.log(req.data.detail);
    res.json(req.data);
}
```

It looks like `req.data` is undefined.

**How am I supposed to retrieve the data from my request in my URL handler?**

Comment: show your response of your app.js fiel

Comment: hello,can u show your server.js file

Comment: if you share your app.js code ,i may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the data from the body of the `req`

```
var qs = require('qs');

app.post('/', function(req,res){
   var body = qs.parse(req.body);
   var detail = body.detail;
   console.log('details',detail); //prints test
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your post doesn't match the AngularJs syntax. Your $http.post should be like ;

```
$http.post('/ticketDetail', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason, in your URL handler you are not supposed to access the field `data: {detail : "test"}` with `req.data` but with `req.body`.

```
app.post("/ticketDetail", function(req, res)
{
    console.log(req.body.detail); // prints "test"
    res.json(req.data);
}
```